# Algebra with differential operators (Alternative forms of the Laplacian in spherical coordinates)

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, laplacian

Given is the following: $$\frac{1}{r^2} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^2  \,\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \right) =  
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2} + \frac{2}{r} \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \frac{1}{r} 
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} \left( r  \, f \right)$$

**My question is:** How can I get to the term on the right $\frac{1}{r} 
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} \left( r  \, f \right)$ from the left term $\frac{1}{r^2} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^2  \,\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \right)$ or the term in the middle $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2} + \frac{2}{r} \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$?

Using the product rule I can easily get from the left term $\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^2  \,\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \right)$ to the term in the middle $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2} + \frac{2}{r} \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$. And I also can get from the term on the right $\frac{1}{r} 
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} \left( r  \, f \right)$ to the term in the middle. So I can verify that the given relation is true. But how to get the the term on the right in the first place is beyond my knowledge.

**Background**:
The Laplacian in spherical coordinates $( r ,\vartheta ,\phi )$ is

$$\Delta f = \frac{1}{r^2} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^2  \,\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \right) +
\frac{1}{r^2 \sin \vartheta}  \frac{\partial}{\partial \vartheta} \left(\sin\vartheta \, \frac{\partial f}{\partial \vartheta} \right) +
\frac{1}{r^2 \sin^2\vartheta}  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \phi^2}\,.
$$

Some problems are easier to solve when the first term is in one of the alternative forms given above. However I don't want to memorize all three forms. I want to remember just the first form, and if I need the others, just derive them with a little bit of algebra.

Answer (score 0):

It can be demonstrated that:
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^2  \,\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \right) &= \frac{1}{r^{2}} \, \left( r^{2} \, \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial r^{2}} + 2 \, r \, \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \right) \\
&= \frac{\partial^{2} f}{ \partial r^{2}} + \frac{2}{r} \, \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} \left( r  \, f \right) &= \frac{1}{r} \, \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r \, \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} + f \right) \tag{2} \\ 
&= \frac{1}{r} \left( r \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial r^{2}} + 2 \, \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \right) \\
&= \frac{\partial^{2} f}{ \partial r^{2}} + \frac{2}{r} \, \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}. \tag{3}
\end{align}
By rearranging the terms, ie starting with (1) and writing in reverse order (3) to (2), one state
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^2  \,\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \right) = \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} \left( r  \, f \right)
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, thats true. However thats not what I was asking. You already started from the third term $\frac{1}{r} 
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} \left( r  \, f \right)$, and showed that the relation is true.

What I wanted to know is: How to get to the third term at all? Imagine you only know the first term $\frac{1}{r^2} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^2  \,\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \right)$. Getting the second term is easy as you've shown using the product rule. But how do I get the third form?

Comment: @StefanD. What was demonstrated was that both operators lead to the same result. With that being know then reverse the order of one of the mini proofs. It is just that simple.